# add slider to UIPageViewController while curling

Tags: slider, uipageviewcontroller

I have created a book which can read the story.
I've used UIPageViewController to add page curl while transitioning from one view to another view.

[image]

I want to add this player view to pages, so it would be very realistic. text and soundPlayer have two different controller. and while paging, Im creating new instance of textViewController and adding text to it's label.
if I add player view to textViewController's view, and after paging I remove it from its superview, the player stop playing.

Im confused how to manage this dilemma!!

I've uploaded my code. I appreciate if someone could help me

**update:**
I could take an screenshot from current state of playerView and add it as subview of textViewController. and set alpha of player = 0 so set it hidden.
after curling the page, I remove the image and set transparency (alpha) of player to 1.
but how can I manage to add this photo on next textViewController too?
as you can see in the below image, it's just set to the current textViewController.

code updated:
http://upload.ugm.ac.id/447paging2.zip

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer posted here:

[how to use static variables in my UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011424/how-to-use-static-variables-in-my-uiviewcontroller/15152424#15152424)

please download the sample code posted there.