# how to use static variables in my UIViewController

Tags: static, singleton, uipageviewcontroller

I stucked in a problem for 2weeks.
I have a UILabel which shows soundPlayer Current duration in my view. I use UIPageViewController so the user navigate throughout the pages(my view) like a real book. but when portion of another view controller appears, the label doesn't show the current progress.(because this is new instance of view controller).
How can I make this UILabel be static? I mean all instance of the ViewController have access to one UIlabel so all of them are only updating one label.
I can't use singeleton design pattern, because UIPageViewController needs at least 2 instance of my view controller.
the soundPlayer shoudn't be allocated every time new insatnce of viewcontroller is creating. how should I solve this dilemma?

you can see an example of my problem in weather live app. see the below image:
[image]

download sample code:
http://upload.ugm.ac.id/300paging.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only change should I did is to create an static AVAudioPlayer

static AVAudioPlayer  *soundPlayer;

soundPalyer is Static so there is one for all of instance objects of this class.

and in ViewDidLoad method:

```
    if (!soundPlayer) {
        soundPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:&error];
    }
```

so when you navigating from one viewController to another viewController, soundPlayer wont initialized again and continue its playing.
thats all.